# Getting error SERVICE_UNAVILABLE when trying to update Anchor Peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

When i am running the code `peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -c mychannel`

I am getting this

> 2021-07-26 12:42:59.856 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect
> block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}

I have started getting this error after I have added more orderers. I am using Raft for orderering service. And fabric-ca for generating certificates

configtx.yaml:

```
  Orderer: &OrdererDefaults # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
  OrdererType: etcdraft

  # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
  # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
  # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
  # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
  # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
  Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050
    - orderer2.example.com:8050
    - orderer3.example.com:9050

  EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
      - Host: orderer.example.com
        Port: 7050
        ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
        ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - Host: orderer2.example.com
        Port: 8050
        ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
        ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - Host: orderer3.example.com
        Port: 9050
        ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
        ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt

    # Options to be specified for all the etcd/raft nodes. The values here
    # are the defaults for all new channels and can be modified on a
    # per-channel basis via configuration updates.
    Options:
      # TickInterval is the time interval between two Node.Tick invocations.
      TickInterval: 500ms

      # ElectionTick is the number of Node.Tick invocations that must pass
      # between elections. That is, if a follower does not receive any
      # message from the leader of current term before ElectionTick has
      # elapsed, it will become candidate and start an election.
      # ElectionTick must be greater than HeartbeatTick.
      ElectionTick: 10

      # HeartbeatTick is the number of Node.Tick invocations that must
      # pass between heartbeats. That is, a leader sends heartbeat
      # messages to maintain its leadership every HeartbeatTick ticks.
      HeartbeatTick: 1

      # MaxInflightBlocks limits the max number of in-flight append messages
      # during optimistic replication phase.
      MaxInflightBlocks: 5

      # SnapshotIntervalSize defines number of bytes per which a snapshot is taken
      SnapshotIntervalSize: 16 MB

  # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
  BatchTimeout: 2s

  # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
  BatchSize:
    # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
    MaxMessageCount: 10

    # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch.
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

    # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
    # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

  # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
  # the orderer side of the network
  Organizations:

  # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
  # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
  #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
    # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
```

docker-compose-file:

```
services:
  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      # - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=none
      - ORDERER_CHANNELPARTICIPATION_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7053
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ../system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
      - 7053:7053
    networks:
      - test

  orderer2.example.com:
    container_name: orderer2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      # - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=8050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=none
      - ORDERER_CHANNELPARTICIPATION_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7053
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ../system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:8050
      - 8053:7053
    networks:
      - test

  orderer3.example.com:
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      # - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=9050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=none
      - ORDERER_CHANNELPARTICIPATION_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_ADMIN_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7053
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ../system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 9050:9050
      - 9053:7053
    networks:
      - test
```

docker container log of orderer.example.com:

```
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 7be 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 7bf 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 7c0 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7c1 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7c2 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 3 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] NewStream -> DEBU 7c3 Created new stream to orderer2.example.com:8050 with ID of 26 and buffer size of 10
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7c4 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 2 on channel mychannel took 98.44µs
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] send -> INFO 7c5 Successfully sent StepRequest to 2 after failed attempt(s) channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] NewStream -> DEBU 7c6 Created new stream to orderer3.example.com:9050 with ID of 26 and buffer size of 10
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7c7 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 3 on channel mychannel took 71.392µs
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] send -> INFO 7c8 Successfully sent StepRequest to 3 after failed attempt(s) channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7c9 Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer3(orderer3.example.com:9050) took 44.832µs 
2021-07-26 21:36:40.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7ca Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer2(orderer2.example.com:8050) took 20.721µs 
2021-07-26 21:36:48.403 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> DEBU 7cb Server TLS handshake completed in 2.630606ms server=Orderer remoteaddress=
2021-07-26 21:36:48.403 UTC [orderer.common.server] Deliver -> DEBU 7cc Starting new Deliver handler
2021-07-26 21:36:48.403 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> DEBU 7cd Starting new deliver loop for 
2021-07-26 21:36:48.404 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> DEBU 7ce Attempting to read seek info message from 
2021-07-26 21:36:48.404 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 7cf [channel: mychannel] Rejecting deliver request for  because of consenter error
2021-07-26 21:36:48.404 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 7d0 Closing Deliver stream
2021-07-26 21:36:48.404 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 7d1 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address= grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=675.251µs
2021-07-26 21:36:48.405 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 7d2 [transport]transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2021-07-26 21:36:48.750 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 7d3 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:48.750 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 7d4 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:48.750 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 7d5 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:48.750 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7d6 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7d7 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 3 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7d8 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 2 on channel mychannel took 4.077µs
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7d9 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 3 on channel mychannel took 3.599µs
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] 1 -> DEBU 7da Stream 26 to orderer3(orderer3.example.com:9050) is aborted
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] 1 -> DEBU 7db Stream 26 to orderer2(orderer2.example.com:8050) is aborted
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7dc Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer3(orderer3.example.com:9050) took 61.407µs but failed due to EOF
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7dd Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer2(orderer2.example.com:8050) took 66.918µs but failed due to EOF
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] serviceStream -> DEBU 7df Stream 26 to (orderer2.example.com:8050) terminated with total lifetime of 7.999445309s
2021-07-26 21:36:48.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] serviceStream -> DEBU 7de Stream 26 to (orderer3.example.com:9050) terminated with total lifetime of 7.999522414s
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 7e0 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 7e1 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 7e2 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7e3 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 3 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7e4 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7e5 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 3 on channel mychannel took 25.709µs
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] logSendFailure -> ERRO 7e6 Failed to send StepRequest to 3, because: EOF channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7e7 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 2 on channel mychannel took 5.017µs
2021-07-26 21:36:56.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] logSendFailure -> ERRO 7e8 Failed to send StepRequest to 2, because: EOF channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.750 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 7e9 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.750 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 7ea 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 7eb 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7ec 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7ed 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 3 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] NewStream -> DEBU 7ee Created new stream to orderer2.example.com:8050 with ID of 27 and buffer size of 10
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7ef Sending msg of 28 bytes to 2 on channel mychannel took 271.523µs
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] send -> INFO 7f0 Successfully sent StepRequest to 2 after failed attempt(s) channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7f1 Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer2(orderer2.example.com:8050) took 130.526µs 
2021-07-26 21:37:04.752 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] NewStream -> DEBU 7f2 Created new stream to orderer3.example.com:9050 with ID of 27 and buffer size of 10
2021-07-26 21:37:04.752 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7f3 Sending msg of 28 bytes to 3 on channel mychannel took 627.237µs
2021-07-26 21:37:04.752 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] send -> INFO 7f4 Successfully sent StepRequest to 3 after failed attempt(s) channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:04.752 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7f5 Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer3(orderer3.example.com:9050) took 98.032µs 
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 7f6 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 7f7 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 7f8 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7f9 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> INFO 7fa 1 [logterm: 1, index: 3] sent MsgPreVote request to 3 at term 1 channel=mychannel node=1
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7fb Sending msg of 28 bytes to 2 on channel mychannel took 4.668µs
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] consensusSent -> DEBU 7fc Sending msg of 28 bytes to 3 on channel mychannel took 2.001µs
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] 1 -> DEBU 7fd Stream 27 to orderer3(orderer3.example.com:9050) is aborted
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 7fe Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer3(orderer3.example.com:9050) took 102.584µs but failed due to EOF
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] serviceStream -> DEBU 7ff Stream 27 to (orderer3.example.com:9050) terminated with total lifetime of 7.999196657s
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] 1 -> DEBU 800 Stream 27 to orderer2(orderer2.example.com:8050) is aborted
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] sendMessage -> DEBU 801 Send of ConsensusRequest for channel mychannel with payload of size 28 to orderer2(orderer2.example.com:8050) took 24.421µs but failed due to EOF
2021-07-26 21:37:12.751 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.step] serviceStream -> DEBU 802 Stream 27 to (orderer2.example.com:8050) terminated with total lifetime of 7.999721572s
```

Actual error on the terminal:

```
Setting anchor peer for org1...
Using organization 1
Fetching channel config for channel mychannel
Using organization 1
Fetching the most recent configuration block for the channel
+ peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -c mychannel
2021-07-26 21:26:40.010 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2021-07-26 21:26:40.012 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
Error: can't read the block: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
Decoding config block to JSON and isolating config to Org1MSPconfig.json
+ configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block
+ jq '.data.data[0].payload.data.config'
configtxlator: error: open config_block.pb: no such file or directory, try --help
+ jq '.channel_group.groups.Application.groups.Org1MSP.values += {"AnchorPeers":{"mod_policy": "Admins","value":{"anchor_peers": [{"host": "peer0.org1.example.com","port": 7051}]},"version": "0"}}' Org1MSPconfig.json
Generating anchor peer update transaction for Org1 on channel mychannel
+ configtxlator proto_encode --input Org1MSPconfig.json --type common.Config
configtxlator: error: Error decoding: error decoding input: error unmarshaling intermediate JSON: EOF
+ configtxlator proto_encode --input Org1MSPmodified_config.json --type common.Config
configtxlator: error: Error decoding: error decoding input: error unmarshaling intermediate JSON: EOF
+ configtxlator compute_update --channel_id mychannel --original original_config.pb --updated modified_config.pb
configtxlator: error: Error computing update: error computing config update: no channel group included for original config
+ configtxlator proto_decode --input config_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate
+ jq .
++ cat config_update.json
+ echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"mychannel", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":{' '"channel_id":' '"",' '"isolated_data":' '{},' '"read_set":' null, '"write_set":' null '}}}}'
+ configtxlator proto_encode --input config_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope
2021-07-26 21:26:40.664 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: ConfigUpdate for channel '' but envelope for channel 'mychannel'
Anchor peer update failed
```

One of the speculation I have for the problem is that orderers are unable to talk to each other because as soon as I remove the additional 2 orderers from consenters(configtx.yaml) everything seems to work
If anyone can provide me any solution it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the second and third orderer not join the channel yet.

The solution is join the second and third orderer to the channel with osnadmin command. Similar command you can found in createChannel.sh in the sample test-network. Here is the command for joining the orderer to the cahnnel

```
# join orderer 2
osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:8053 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER2_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER2_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY" >&log.txt

# join orderer 3
osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:9053 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER3_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER3_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY" >&log.txt
```

Full function in createChannel.sh will be :

```
createChannel() {
    setGlobals 1
    # Poll in case the raft leader is not set yet
    local rc=1
    local COUNTER=1
    while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ] ; do
        sleep $DELAY
        set -x
        infoln "Orderer join channel"
        osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY" >&log.txt
        infoln "Orderer2 join channel"
        osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:8053 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER2_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER2_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY" >&log.txt
        infoln "Orderer3 join channel"
        osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:9053 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER3_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER3_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY" >&log.txt
        res=$?
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
        let rc=$res
        COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
    done
    cat log.txt
    verifyResult $res "Channel creation failed"
}
```

Note : make sure you have added the Orderer2 and Orderer3 TLS certificate Variable in envVar.sh

Answer (score 0):

If you think the added orderer is not working,
you can check orderer's raft status here

http://[YOUR ORDERER IP]:8443/metrics

the port 8443 defined in orderer.yaml

```
Operations:
      ListenAddress: [] < -- here
```

and Ctrl + F, search "consensus_etcdraft_is_leader"

Comment: Browser is allowing to access http://[YOUR ORDERER IP]:8443/metrics. Can you guide me a little more on this?

Comment: for example,
 ( consensus : Raft ) 
orderer1 : 192.168.0.2:7050, 

orderer2 : 192.168.0.3:7050, 

orderer3 : 192.168.0.3:7050.

You can check the raft status. ( Who is the leader or the follower ) 
192.168.0.2:8443/metrics -> orderer1 is the leader or the follower?, 

192.168.0.3:8443/metrics -> orderer2 is the leader or the follower?, 

192.168.0.4:8443/metrcis -> orderer3 is the leader or the follower?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that this answer doesn't directly apply to OPs question but it somewhat applies to the same `warning`, so i am putting this here. It might help someone.

###### Create application channel command (execute from peerOrg admin cli)

```bash
peer channel create \
  -c mychannel \
  -o orderer-org0:6050 \
++  -t 50s 
  -f "/pathtoartifacts/artifacts/mychannel.tx" \
  --outputBlock "/pathtoartifacts/artifacts/mychannel.block" \
  --tls \
  --cafile "/pathtoorderer/msp/tlscacerts/ca.pem"
```

The command timed out, returning multiple times the warning bellow.

> 2021-07-26 12:42:59.856 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect block, but got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}

##### Solution

After add the `-t` timeout flag to a higher value, the channel block was successfully created and stored to the output artifacts path.

I am not sure of the reason, but i assume due to the kubernetes based hyperledger fabric deployment, the inter-containers (orderers, endorses, admin-cli) communication is a bit more slow, than when running everything in localhost.

> Note: the warning still appear, but i now receive a block and the expected output artifact in the artifacts folder.